# Grapic output not working in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

I am trying to draw a queue of clients implemented by extending the JPanel class and using the Graphics methods. However I can't get an output from the graphic JFrame.
This is my class in which i wish to draw.

```
public class Simulating extends JPanel{

    // Server server;
    //private ArrayList<JPanel> remember=new ArrayList<JPanel>(server.no_list);s
    public Simulating() {}

    protected void colorareComponente(Graphics gr) {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <Server.listele.length; i++) {
            int y = 0;
            // desenez casele
            deseneazaCasa(gr, x, y,i);
            for (int j = 0; j <Server.listele[i].getSize(); j++) {
                y =y+ 25;
                // desenezClienti
                //  SimulareCoada.cozi[i].getClientCurent(j).getId()
                int id =  Server.listele[i].getTask(j).getId()+ 1;
                deseneazaClient(gr, x, y, id);
            }
            x =x+ 100;
        }

    }
    private void deseneazaCasa(Graphics g, int x, int y,int i) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 20);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("Server"+i+1 , x + 20, y + 20);
        this.repaint();
    }

    private void deseneazaClient(Graphics g, int x, int y, int id) {
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 35, 35);
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(id), x + 8, y + 16);
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void rewrite() {
         this.repaint();
    }
}
```

I am implementing it in an initalizer method in another class by this:

```
public Simulating sim=new Simulating();
public static   JFrame frm= new JFrame();
frm.setLayout(null);
frm.setBounds(10, 10, 450, 450);
sim.setBounds(10, 10, 200,200);
frm.add(sim);
frm.setTitle("Simulare servere");
frm.setVisible(true);
frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(frm.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

However there doesn;t seem to be any output.
I am calling sim in another method to repaint the frames:

```
public void run(){
    this.initializeServer();

    for (Server.currentTime = 0; Server.taskCount > 0; Server.currentTime++){
        int TimeHours =calculateTimeHour(currentTime);
        int TimeMinutes = calculateTimeMinute(currentTime);
        writeHourConsole(TimeHours,TimeMinutes);
        writeHourLog(TimeHours,TimeMinutes);
        this.Log.setLog(keepingLog);
        this.Log.repaint();
        int val=0;
        if(val==0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < taskurile.size(); i++){
                if (taskurile.get(i).getGettingTime() == Server.currentTime){
                    int index = taskurile.get(i).chooseLista(this);
                    this.listele\[index\].addTaskLast(taskurile.get(i));            
                    System.out.println("\n Taskul " + i + " a fost preluat la " + decimal.format(TimeHours) + ":" + decimal.format(TimeMinutes) + "si este procesat pentru " +  taskurile.get(i).getProcessTime());
                    Server.appendLog("\n Taskul " + i + " a fost preluat la " + decimal.format(TimeHours) + ":" + decimal.format(TimeMinutes) + "si este procesat pentru " +  taskurile.get(i).getProcessTime()+ "de serverul " + taskurile.get(i).chooseLista(this));
                    sim.rewrite();
                    this.Log.setLog(keepingLog);
                    this.Log.repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get:
[image: result]

There is a log panel that keeps track of events which works just fine. And I have no errors or exception messages.

Could somebody explain why it's not working?
Thank you!

Comment: Read about [custom painting in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: Ie. you never invoke the paintComponent() method directly as the above tutorial link will explain. Custom painting code is added to the paintComponent() method. The tutorial has working examples you can download and play with.